# get connection timeout while checking a port on server

Tags: linux, port

I don't have a any deep knowledge regarding the server, but recently I got some issue with mail on one server.

I have tried this command

```
telnet 77.242.116.45 587
```

and it gives me

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

I am attaching the port image and I don't have any idea is which post is running and which is not.

[image]

can anyone please guide me on this.

After trying Stephen Kitt's solution I got this error.

#### Connection closed by foreign host.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process listening on port 587 is bound to 127.0.0.1, so it will only accept connections on localhost; you should find that

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 587
```

will open a connection.

If you need to change that, you’ll have to change the configuration of whatever program is running so that it listens on the appropriate addresses.

Comment: I have updated the issue I got "Connection closed by foreign host" after running your given command. @StephenKitt

Comment: That’s normal, you’re not sending anything on the connection so the server closes it. The fact that you get a 220 response proves that your connection attempt was successful.

Comment: I am still not able to send mail through 587 port form this server.
My server is running on IP, is that domain required to send mail? 
@StephenKitt

Comment: Where are you trying to send mail from? If it’s somewhere other than the mail server, you need to change the configuration so that it will listen on the appropriate addresses. Otherwise, you need to configure your sending program to connect to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I am sending a mail threw "Zivver" ( my mail server), the issue is the port and now it is solved. port is closed by the server guy.